# ConEmu + ls -- 256 colors not working

Tags: windows-10, colors, ls, conemu, cmder

I'm using ConEmu (specifically Cmder's version). Running 'cmd', it supports 256 colors (top).

However, I can't get other programs to run in 256 color mode. I've tried Perl (middle) and `ls` (bottom), but both run in 8/16 color mode.

[image: Cmder - 256 vs 8 color mode]

Any suggestions on how to fix this. Mostly I'd like `ls` to work in 256 color mode.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the **official** docs contains all answers:

- [256-color mode requirements and limitations](https://conemu.github.io/en/Xterm256Colors.html#xterm_256_color_mode_requirements)
- [cygwin and ANSI](https://conemu.github.io/en/CygwinAnsi.html)
- [cygwin/msys connector](https://conemu.github.io/en/CygwinMsysConnector.html)

Why not to read them?

To enable 256 colors in `ls` you have to run [cygwin/msys connector](https://conemu.github.io/en/CygwinMsysConnector.html) and disable backscroll buffer with `-cur_console:h0` while starting your task. Of course, that must not be `{cmd}` task, but `{bash}` task with connector.

Comment: I think I have the settings right: 'TrueMod (24bit color) support', 'ANSI X3.64 / xterm 256 colors’, and ‘Inject ConEmuHk’ are all enabled. I can' find where to turn off scrolling. `perl 256colors2.pl -cur_console:h0` produces the same output as above, except now the first line of the prompt is printed twice.

Comment: With the second part of your comment, are you saying that 256 color mode for `ls` only works on `{bash}` and not `{cmd}`?

Comment: I did not say that. Read the answer again.