# Getting 256 colors from Cygwin within cmder/ConEmu

Tags: command-line, bash, terminal, cygwin, conemu

I am trying to get 256 colors under Cygwin while running cmder. Generally, what I am doing is opening a terminal session in Windows 10 by typing "cmd" into Start. If I need to open a Cygwin terminal, I generally enter "bash" into that cmder instance.

When I run `tput colors` from within either the cmder prompt or the Cygwin terminal running within cmder, the system returns `8`.

I have reviewed the following similar threads and references: 
[ConEmu + ls -- 256 colors not working](https://superuser.com/questions/1030047/conemu-ls-256-colors-not-working)
https://conemu.github.io/en/CygwinMsysConnector.html

(some links omitted due to low reputation limitations, see comments, but I am familiar with how Cygwin processes ANSI internally before passing it, parsed, to a ConEmu terminal)

I have downloaded the cygwin/msys connector and, indeed, `tput colors` returns 256 when I run the connector. What I would like to do is find a way to integrate this connector more directly into my workflow. I have environment variables that tie Cygwin more directly into my Windows terminal environment within cmder and sometimes run Cygwin commands from outside of a bash prompt, e.g. running vim on some file from a windows prompt, so simply running the connector every time I'd like access to the Cygwin bash isn't quite a complete solution for me. I'd like to know how to "wire up" this connector more directly so that it's running automatically, in the background, in lieu of running bash directly. I don't know if that makes any sense at all.

What I'm looking for is what environment variables, tasks, etc I need to set specifically to make this linkage happen more seamlessly.

edit: I realized it may be important to point out that I have cygwin's path put into my system environment variables.

Comment: Output from cat AnsiColors256.ans: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Hc2Hf.png ... Here's what some of my cmder settings look like. Hopefully it's useful information: ... cmder Tasks: http://imgur.com/bkSyLQG  ... cmder Environment Variables: http://imgur.com/bkSyLQG ... Cygwin.bat: http://imgur.com/2GAVzse ... Apologies for the clumsy comment edit, formatting limitations.

Comment: Why do you crop screenshots? Neither title nor status bars are visible.

Comment: Privacy, largely. Was there specific information you would find helpful that I might provide? I hadn't realized the content of the title / statusbars was relevant. Looking back more closely, what you may be looking for is my ConEmu version, which is ConEmu 160710 [32] {Stable}.

Comment: Generally I'm interested in status bar: modes, sizes, visible rect, etc.

Comment: check TERM value. with `TERM=xterm-16color` I have on mintty `$ tput colors` `16`

Comment: @matzeri In which dotfile? That was always unclear to me from guides I was reading.

Comment: @Maximus I'll be sure to get you better screenshots in the morning.

Comment: Use `echo $TERM`,  TERM is usually defined by the terminal program before starting the bash.

Comment: @matzeri `echo $TERM` returns `cygwin`

Comment: Terminal after running commands suggested by matzeri, @Maximus the statusbar is included in this screenshot. http://imgur.com/ud0ELuY

edit: I also totally get that this is a Cygwin issue and not a ConEmu issue, just trying to figure out how to implement the msys connector in my workflow.

Comment: Sorry, but your screenshot does not show "Terminal modes". What is there? "W"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To couple cygwin with ConEmu.
Tested on `ConEmu 160714` with `terminals.v0.7.4.7z`

https://github.com/Maximus5/cygwin-connector/releases

Extract `conemu-cyg-64.exe` from `terminals.v0.7.4.7z` and copied on `C:\cygwin64\bin`

Modify the Predefined task on `Settings->Startup->Tasks`
from

```
set CHERE_INVOKING=1 & C:\CygWin64\bin\bash.exe --login -i -new_console:C:"C:\CygWin\Cygwin.ico"
```

to

```
set CHERE_INVOKING=1 & C:\cygwin64\bin\conemu-cyg-64.exe  /usr/bin/bash.exe --login -i -new_console:C:"C:\cygwin64\Cygwin.ico"
```

Set the `Settings-> Features -> Colors -> Scheme` to `xterm`

The 256colors are not fantastic, they look more only 16, but I guess is due to the mismatch  between the connector and ConEmu

[image]